# Problem with redux-persist along with SSR. Hydration failed

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I have a React SSR application where I use redux-toolkit. After connecting redux-persist (based on the redux-toolkit documentation), redux-persist works correctly on the client. But on SSR I get a hydration error like Text content did not match. Server: "One string", Client: "Another string". What am I doing wrong?

Here is a code

client store.ts

```
import {
  configureStore,
  type PreloadedState,
  type StateFromReducersMapObject,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import { api } from "./api";
import { layoutSlice } from "./layoutSlice";
import { persistConfig, planSlice } from "./plansSlice";

const reducer = {
  [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
  [layoutSlice.name]: layoutSlice.reducer,
  [planSlice.name]: persistReducer(persistConfig, planSlice.reducer),
};

export const initStore = (preloadedState?: PreloadedStateType) =>
  configureStore({
    reducer,
    preloadedState,
    middleware: (getDefault) =>
      getDefault({
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        },
      }).concat(api.middleware),
  });
```

client index.tsx

```
const store = initStore(STORE);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

persistor.subscribe(() => {
  const { bootstrapped } = persistor.getState();

  if (bootstrapped) {
    ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
      container,
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <LanguageApp
            initialI18nStore={I18N_STORE || {}}
            initialLanguage={I18N_INITIAL_LANGUAGE || ""}
          />
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
});
```

part of server.tsx

```
const appHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.originalUrl}>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={req.i18n}>
        <Provider store={preloadedStore}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </I18nextProvider>
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  return indexHTML
    .replace(
      '<div id="app"></div>',
      ` 
      <div id="app">${appHTML}</div> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
      window._SSR_STORE_STATE_ = 
      ${JSON.stringify(preloadedStore.getState())};
      window.initialI18nStore = ${JSON.stringify(initialI18nStore)};
      window.initialLanguage = "${initialLanguage}";
      </script>
    `
    )
```

**Thanks for your time!**